# Why is MVC 4 Razor escaping ampersand when using HTML.Raw in a title attribute

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4

We recently upgraded to MVC 4 and now we are having titles in our links not display correctly. The problem is before HTML.Raw would not escape & in our title attributes, but now it does. Below is my sample code:

```
<a title="@Html.Raw("Shoe Size 6&#189;-8")">Test</a>
```

Which produces the following markup:

```
<a title="Shoe Size 6&amp;#189;-8">Test</a>
```

The only solution I found so far was to put the entire anchor into a string and then HTML.Raw that string.

[Why is Html.Raw escaping ampersand in anchor tag in ASP.NET MVC 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11963453/why-is-html-raw-escaping-ampersand-in-anchor-tag-in-asp-net-mvc-4).

This is a very ugly solution and I am hoping there is a better alternative.

Comment: This has been fixed in MVC 5.0. Check the [bug report](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/393)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

While it is only a small step less ugly workaround, you can simply `@Html.Raw` the full attribute name and value.

```
<a @Html.Raw("title=\"Show Size 6&#189;-8\"")>Test</a>
```

Results in:

```
<a title="Show Size 6&#189;-8">Test</a>
```

Answer (score 8):

If you can't do the workaround listed above, I have a patched base-class you could try injecting via web.config. Check it out at https://gist.github.com/4036121

Comment: Nice - and thank you for [queuing it to be fixed](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/393).