# Razor - @Html.Raw() still encoding &amp; in meta tag attributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

When I use @Html.Raw(mystring) normal it renders properly example:

```
@{ ViewBag.Title = "My Site&reg;"; }
<title>@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Title)</title>
```

Will properly render `<title>My Site&reg;</title>` but when I use it in an attribute:

```
<meta name="description" content="@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Title)" />
```

It renders `<meta name="description" content="My Site&amp;reg;" />` which is not correct because then it will not render the registered mark.

How do you correct this behavior?

Comment: Duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11963453/why-is-html-raw-escaping-ampersand-in-anchor-tag-in-asp-net-mvc-4 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12321616/why-is-mvc-4-razor-escaping-ampersand-when-using-html-raw-in-a-title-attribute

Comment: @Ek0nomik It's not really a duplicate because no one resolved that question. They're suggestion was load the whole <meta /> tag into the string and that is stupid do to on every page.

Comment: You can just include the attribute name in the parameter to `.Raw` as shown in the second question linked above.  You're going to have to do a work around as this is a bug:  http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/393.

Comment: @Ek0nomik I didn't see the second question when I first looked. It had the better solution. You can post it as an answer if you want. Otherwise I'm going to post my code solution so it's available.

Comment: No worries.  I added an answer.  Best of luck!

Answer (score 8):

As [patridge pointed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12321616/why-is-mvc-4-razor-escaping-ampersand-when-using-html-raw-in-a-title-attribute) out in his answer you can just include the attribute markup in the parameter to `.Raw`.

In your case that would result in something similar to the following:

```
<meta name="description" @Html.Raw("content=\"My Site&amp;reg;\"") />
```

Comment: @Justin Helgerson In deed this is the only way I made it work, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your _layout.cshtml:

```
<title>@{var title = new HtmlString(ViewBag.Title);}@title</title>
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the tip-top solution:

```
@{ ViewBag.Title = "My Site&reg;"; }
<title>@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Title)</title>
<meta name="description" content="@HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(ViewBag.Title)" />
```