# @Html.Raw insists on encoding quotes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

`MVC4` razor view. Given that a string `backgroundImage` is set like this:

```
backgroundImage = string.Format("background: url('{0}') top left no-repeat;", project.MainImage);
```

Why does this

```
<div class="spotlight slide teaser-text" id="@slideId" style="@Html.Raw(backgroundImage)">
```

produce

```
<div class="spotlight slide teaser-text" id="spotlight-0" style="background: url(&#39;/media/215/spotlight01.jpg&#39;) top left no-repeat;">
```

`Html.Raw`, `new MvcHtmlString` and `MvcHtmlString.Create` all behave similarly.

I would **expect** it to produce

```
<div class="spotlight slide teaser-text" id="spotlight-0" style="background: url('/media/215/spotlight01.jpg') top left no-repeat;">
```

(note the quotes).

Comment: `Html.Raw()` just returns an `HtmlString`, and `MvcHtmlString` extends `HtmlString`; I think what you see is expected?

Comment: @radium: No; the whole point of those is to prevent escaping.

Comment: Just tried on MVC3 and got the expected results (I don't have MVC4 on this machine). So maybe it changed in 4.

Comment: What happens if you just write it out directly, rather than putting it in an attribute?

Comment: @JoeEnos It is encoded.  Curiously, if it is output not as an attribute value, it is **not** encoded.

Comment: Your result and what you expect are equivalent.  Is something not working, or do you just not want the single quote to be encoded?

Comment: @radium exactly - the single quote character is being encoded to `&#39;` in the style attribute.  I don't want that.

Comment: Well `WebUtility.HtmlEncode()` does encode single quotes.  I'm guessing some part of the Razor engine applies that to attribute values as an XSS prevention.  Interested to hear the answer.

Comment: Can't find an actual answer, but I'm seeing that others are seeing the same thing [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12321616/why-is-mvc-4-razor-escaping-ampersand-when-using-html-raw-in-a-title-attribute) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11963453/why-is-html-raw-escaping-ampersand-in-anchor-tag-in-asp-net-mvc-4). Appears to be the framework's way of "helping you out" when writing inside of HTML attributes by preventing invalid characters in attributes. I'd expect that even though it looks weird, it should still work ok, right?

Comment: It does in (at least) IE10 and Chrome27, but the fact that I'm sending duff HTML to the client bothers me.  Looks like the answer is "by design", and an acceptable workaround is to put it all into a separate style section.

Answer (score 3):

I have had a look at the compiled DLL for a razor template containing this markup. As far as I can see, the issue is this.

`Html.Raw` turns a string into an `HtmlString`. `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` treats `IHtmlString` instances differently to normal strings, in that it doesn't apply Html encoding.

When the programmatically defined string is given in the context of the attribute, a call is made to

```
this.WriteAttribute(...)
```

with data appropriate to generate the attribute. Part of this data is the HtmlString generated by the call to `Html.Raw`. Another part is a flag indicating that the value is not a literal.

Because of the not-literal flag status, the `WriteAttribute` method eventually calls `HtmlEncode`. But it calls this **not** on the `HtmlString`, but on the **string value** of this object. So you do end up with an HTML encoded value in the output.

Outside the context of an attribute, the call is made to

```
this.Write(...)
```

and this doesn't suffer from the same problem. So it seems like a bug to me (at least if I've accurately traced it all through).