# Unable to decode a URL string encoded by MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, string, url, view, decoding

I'm passing a string with a URL from the controller to the view (using a model).
While the string is in the controller, it is not encoded, but in the view the URL is encoded.

URL before encoding:

`http://app.xpinator.com/FacebookPayments/FacebookDesktopAdData?paymentCode=s5usd920k&userLocale=en-us&ver=v3.0.1`

URL after encoding:

`http://localhost/FacebookPayments/FacebookPaymentItemData?paymentcode=v250usd45000k&amp;userlocale=en-us&amp;ver=v3.0.1`

Relevant line in the view:

`<meta property="og:url" content="@Model.URL" />`

I want to display a decoded URL in the view. I tried using `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode`, `HttpUtility.UrlDecode` and `Html.Raw` - nothing worked.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

Thanks to Daniel's comment I realized that the encoding is happening only when the URL is in a meta property. when its a "displayable" HTML there is no encoding.

Anyway, still looking for a solution.

Comment: Are you sure `@Html.Raw(Model.URL)` didn't work?

Comment: Sure. I tried that more than once...

Comment: That works for me, check [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Gk9lXi)

Comment: Thanks, but I see that in your fiddle the URL is not encoded even if you omit the `@Html.Raw`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After realizing the problem occurs only with meta tags, I've found this thread:
[Why is Html.Raw escaping ampersand in anchor tag in ASP.NET MVC 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11963453/why-is-html-raw-escaping-ampersand-in-anchor-tag-in-asp-net-mvc-4)

I managed solve the problem with the suggested workaround to make the entire meta tag part of the raw value.

like this:

Controller:

```
model.URL = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", "<meta property=\"og:url\" content=\"", paymentItemOG.URL, "\" />");
```

View:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="@Model.Image" />
@Html.Raw(Model.URL)
<meta property="og:description" content="@Model.Description" />
```

Page view-source:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://localhost/content/images/75x75_fullLogo.png" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://localhost/FacebookPayments/FacebookPaymentItemData?paymentcode=v250usd45000k&userlocale=en-us&ver=v3.0.1" />
<meta property="og:description" content="texttexttext" />
```

Now it works great.